# OCamlbuild and camlp4.macro

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, camlp4

I have a project where several of the OCaml source files use IFDEF.  Is there a simple way to tell OCamlbuild that all .ml files for this project should be preprocessed by camlp4.macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the root of your project, you can create a `_tag` file containing:

```
true: camlp4of
```

here, the `f` suffix means means "full camlp4", that is `camlp4o` with all standard extensions (parsers, grammars, quotations, macros, and list comprehensions). For more details, see the [manual](http://brion.inria.fr/gallium/index.php/Using_Camlp4).